# Gtk# on Linux open webpage?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

Am using Mono C# with Gtk# to write app for Mac OS X and Linux.

How can i open a web page inside the app? I tried to see if it have a webview container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need WebKit + WebKit-Sharp: https://github.com/mono/webkit-sharp